# Is this a correct unit test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I am trying to get the basics of unit tests and all the tutorials are using huge examples. Also I have written the following code and the test and would like to know if this is correct:

```
class Foo
{
  public bool TwoDecisions(int X, int Y)
  {
    if(X>Y)
       return true;
    else return false;
  }
}

TEST
 public class FooTests  
   {  
     [Test]  
     public void TwoDecisions_TRUE()  
     {  
      Foo f=new Foo();
      bool expected = true;  
      bool actual = FooTests.TwoDecision(10,9)
       Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);  
     }  
   }
```

Comment: What happens when you try it? Also, your method could be written `return X > Y;`

Comment: Actually I cannot try it (out of home now) so I am learning and just preparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *a* unit test, so in that way it is correct. But is it the only test that this class requires? no. You are only testing the branch of your `if` statement that returns true. You should also test the case where X<Y in order to fully 'cover' your code.

Comment: I see, I should have another test method returning false and maybe two: one for "=" and another for "<".

Comment: @TerryS correct - you should seek to exercise all of the code within your class. These means writing unit tests that test all the paths through your code.

Comment: And don't forget the case when x == y

Comment: @Jocke - that depends on whether you are black-box or clear-box testing. In this case, we can see the implementation, so using clear-box testing, we can ensure branch coverage with just two tests cases. But, if we could not see the implementation, i.e. the box was black, I would agree that a test case for x==y would make sense.